# Al rotar un elemento no puedo posicionarlo a la izquierda de forma fija

Tags: css

Al rotar un elemento 90º no puedo colocarlo en posición fixed a la izquierda del todo?

Gracias

```css
footer{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
```

```html
        <footer>
            <p>
                Creado por <a href="#" id="alvaro">Álvaro Torres</a>
            </p>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad: [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
footer{
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;    
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Creado por <a href="#" id="alvaro">Álvaro Torres</a></p>
</footer>
```

**Info soporte:** Prácticamente todos los navegadores modernos lo soportan ([ver compatibilidades](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode#Browser_compatibility))

Comment: Genial @Aldanux, justo lo que estaba buscando. Es curioso porque no aparece en la guía de css3 que tengo. He encontrado algo en developer.mozilla.org

Mil gracias
:)

Answer (score 0):

Ya está a la izquierda, lo que pasa es que esa diferencia con el margen de la pantalla corresponde a la diferencia que hay entre alto y ancho del contenido.
Yo lo que haría sería calcular con javascript el "height" del elemento footer y restárselo mediante css a la propiedad "left".